# When using snap-scroll my site is being cut off on mobile devices (Tested with android google chrome)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, mobile

I am super new to html, css and java- literally just started.
As a "learning-by-doing" project I am creating a website for a friend of mine.

I am using snap-scrolling to be able to "jump" sites.
Unfortunately on my mobile (android phone) the bottom of each page is cut-off due to the Chrome Browser navigation.

I was told to not use 100vh but 100% instead. Did so and still can't find my mistake.

The website is live at [LINK](https://robert-ullrich.great-site.net/).

The section with the most visible issue at the bottom is the last page.
the Snapscroll div is wrapping all sites.

I am wrapping all pages with the snap-scroll which only works with 100vh?
the pages themselve are set to 100% height.

```
.snap_scroll {
max-width: 100%;
height: 100vh;
scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
overflow-y: scroll; 
max-height: -webkit-fill-available;
}
```

```
.contact{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: url(./img/app_background_2.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  position: relative;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```